# 'This socket is closed' when stdout is listened in Mocha test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

This test

```
it.only('should not throw', () => {
    var output = '';

    function callback(data) {
        output += data.toString();
    }

    process.stdout.on('data', callback); // error is thrown at this line
    // ...
    process.stdout.removeListener('data', callback);
})
```

throws an error:

```
Error: This socket is closed                                                                           
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:679:19)                                                
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:730:8)                                                        
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:331:12)                                                            
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:317:5)                                                       
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:243:11)                                         
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:657:40)                                                        
    at Console.log (console.js:43:16)                                                                  
    at Runner.<anonymous> (node_modules\mocha\lib\reporters\spec.js:80:13)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)                                                                      
    at Runner.emit (events.js:191:7)                                                                   
    at Runner.fail (node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:251:8)               
    at Runner.uncaught (node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:757:8)           
    at process.uncaught (node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:839:10)         
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)                                                                       
    at process.emit (events.js:188:7)                                                                  
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:297:26)
```

Where `node_modules\mocha\lib\reporters\spec.js:80:13` are these Mocha lines:

```
  runner.on('fail', function(test) {
    console.log(indent() + color('fail', '  %d) %s'), ++n, test.title);
  });
```

It's supposed to test code that outputs to `process.stdout` with `spawn`, but I wasn't able to get to this part; the error is thrown instantly on `process.stdout.on('data', ...)` call.

The problem persists with latest Mocha (5.2.0) and default configuration, a reporter in use doesn't affect the result.

What is going on and how can `process.stdout` be listened? If this is impossible, how can stdout from spawned process be tested in Mocha otherwise?

Comment: `spawn` has an option `stdio` that you could use to pass a custom 'stdout' stream to. Not sure if you can actually listen on `process.stdout` for `data` events, given that it's probably a _writable_ stream and `data` is a _readable_ event.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the notice. Indeed, this was the actual problem with the code, slipped my mind when I issued a bounty. Since `spawn` was hard-coded to use `process.stdout`, seems like this requires to patch `process.stdout._write` to intercept data.

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to reproduce the error: `process.stdout.on('data', callback); // error is thrown at this line`. So hard to say why it breaks for you. Anyway `process.stdout` is a writeable stream, so `data` event is not supported. On the other hand `childProcess.stdout` is a readable stream from parent perspective.

The easiest way to intercept stdout of a child process is to:

```
const ch = spawn(...)
ch.stdout.on('data', d => ...) // 'd' is a buffer
```

If you want to test against stdout of an arbitrary spawn process I am afraid you need to pass a custom writeable stream as subprocess's stdout, when spawning the process. The stream needs to be based on a file descriptor, so simple `Duplex` will not work unfortunately.

Here is a possible setup:

*process.js*

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

module.exports = (outStream) => {
  console.log('PARENT')
  const s = spawn('node', [`${__dirname}/child.js`], { stdio: ['ignore', outStream] })

  return () => {
    console.log('PARENT-DISPOSE')
    s.kill()
  }
}
```

*child.js*

```
process.stdout.write('FROM CHILD')
setTimeout(() => process.stdout.write('FROM CHILD END'), 100)
```

*process.spec.js*

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const fs = require('fs')

const process = require('./process.js')

// path to temporary file
const commF = `${__dirname}/comm`

it('test spawn', (done) => {
  const w = fs.createWriteStream(commF)
  let dispose

  w.on('open', () => {
    dispose = process(w)
  })

  // unfortunately I was not able to make fs.createReadStram to read data in real-time
  // so here we use another subprocess just for that
  let readProcess = spawn('tail', ['-f', commF])

  readProcess.stdout.on('data', x => {
    const d = x && x.toString()
    console.log('TEST', d) // only logs from child are present here
    if (d.startsWith('FROM CHILD END')) {
      w.close()
      fs.unlinkSync(commF)
      dispose()
      readProcess.kill()
      done()
    }
  })
}).timeout(500)
```

Not saying that this is the best way to do it: it could be abstracted away for re-usability and the `tail` dependency may be removed.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. This is not always possible but I suppose yes, that's how testable code should be written.